# How to conditionally provision Azure point to site vpn in Terraform?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

How do you conditionally provision a point to site VPN for the current Azure VPN Gateway? I want a P2S VPN for dev/qa VPN Gateway but not prod.  I tried using a count attribute with a boolean variable but terraform does not like this (vpn_client_configuration.0: invalid or unknown key: count)

```
vpn_client_configuration {
    count = "${var.p2s_vpn_enabled}" 

    address_space =  ["${var.p2s_vpn_address_space}"]

    root_certificate {
      name = "${var.p2s_vpn_root_cert_name}"
      public_cert_data = "${var.p2s_vpn_root_cert_base64_data}"
    }       
  }
```

Terraform 11 for windows

Comment: which terraform version are you using currently?

Comment: Terraform 11 / AzureRM Provider 1.29.0

Comment: What do you mean `I want a P2S VPN for dev/qa VPN Gateway but not prod.`? If you do not want P2S vpn connection, you do not need to set the  `vpn_client_configuration` block in prod VPN block as `vpn_client_configuration` is Optional.

Comment: @NancyXiong Dev/QA environments should have P2S vpn config.  Prod should not.  Trying to use same script across all environments by introducing conditional deployment using terraform 'count' attribute.  Count should be 1 in DEV/QA environments but 0 in prod environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error happened because the **[count](https://www.terraform.io/intro/examples/count.html)** parameter works on resources level. The `vpn_client_configuration` is a optional argument in [azurerm_virtual_network_gateway](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/virtual_network_gateway.html) block. You could try to use `count` in the VPN gateway block level, something will be like this,

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_network_gateway" "test" {
  count = "${var.p2s_vpn_enabled}"
  name                = "test"
  location            = "${azurerm_resource_group.test.location}"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.test.name}"

  type     = "Vpn"
  vpn_type = "RouteBased"
...
}
```

Additionally, there is a good article sharing about [Terraform tips & tricks: loops, if-statements, and gotchas](https://blog.gruntwork.io/terraform-tips-tricks-loops-if-statements-and-gotchas-f739bbae55f9)

> In Terraform, a boolean true is converted to a 1 and a boolean false
>   is converted to a 0.
>
> If you set count to 1 on a resource, you get one copy of that resource
>   and if you set count to 0, that resource is not created at all.

Hope this could help you.